# jquery .keyup .keypress do not fire, but the function is called on page reload

Tags: jquery

Any reason why the following code would not fire on keypress but would on page reload?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#weight').keypress(valNum("weight", "weight"));    

function valNum(number, clas){
    var name = $("#"+number).val();
    var reg = /^([0-9\-\ \.]{2,6})$/;
    if(!reg.test(name)){
    $("."+clas+" .nogood").show();
    $("."+clas+" .good").hide();
    }else{
    $("."+clas+" .good").show();
    $("."+clas+" .nogood").hide();
    }
}
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
$('#weight').keypress(valNum("weight", "weight"));
```

To:

```
$('#weight').keypress(function(){
    valNum("weight", "weight");
});
```

---

With your previous statement, problem was that `valNum` function was getting executed ***immediately*** because of `("weight", "weight")`. That's how you call a JS function immediately eg `func()`. However, `keyup` needs a ***callback*** function which is exactly what we have provided it with in latter case.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that you're not passing a function reference (as you thought), but rather the result of calling `valNum("weight", "weight")`, to the `.keypress()` function.

If you want to call an existing function with parameters, you'll need to wrap it in an anonymous function, like so:

```
$('#weight').keypress(function() {
    valNum("weight", "weight");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Like any other function or method, jQuery's `.keypress()` method accepts an argument. This is where you pass the event handler function as an argument. What you're doing, however, is **NOT** passing the function `valNum()` as an argument; you're actually executing the `valNum()` function. Any time you see `()` after a function name, that executes the function. Instead, you just need to wrap the `valNum()` function in an anonymous, *non*-executing function:

```
$('#weight').keypress(function(){
    valNum("weight", "weight");
});
```

The syntax can obscure it, but the argument we're now passing to the `.keypress()` method is:

```
function(){
    valNum("weight", "weight");
}
```

This is the function that gets called when the `keypress` event fires on the bound element. When this anonymous function is called, *then* it calls your `valNum()` function.

This solves both of your issues: `valNum()` will not be exected immediately, and instead it will run in response to the `keypress` event.

Let me know if you have questions -- this is touching on some pretty important topics in JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks, I think I get it, although let's say that valNum did not accept any arguments, and this was code: $('#weight').keypress(valNum);

Comment: because in that case you're actually passing the function to `.keypress()` as an argument rather than executing the function (no parentheses)